# Is it possible to upload on server only that part of file that I changed or added?

Tags: curl, upload

For example I have text file `bbb.txt` it's path is `http://example.com/bbb.txt`. The content of file will be :

`Hello WORLD!`

But now I want to add string `Hello SO!` to it. Is it possible by using curl library, upload only `Hello SO` in order to get such text on server:
 `Hello WORLD! Hello SO!`

Comment: I'm afraid you need server-side processing for that, not only a plain HTTP server. If you can place some PHP file in the server side that can do the job, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such thing as "ranges" for standard HTTP uploads (PUTs). If you want to, you can write a server-side that understands some header or format (over HTTP) and then make sure your client (like for example curl) can send data using that.